# Can't connect to AWS PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psql

I'm trying to login to a newly created PostgreSQL DB instance created using AWS's RDS service.

This is the command I've been running (I've redacted the sensitive info):

```
psql \
 --host=my_aws_end_point \
 --port=5432 \
 --username the_username \
 --password the_password \
 --dbname=ebdb
```

For the security group associated with the instance I have allowed the following inbound connections:

```
PostgreSQL TCP 5432
PostgreSQL TCP 5432 My_IP
PostgreSQL TCP 5432 0.0.0.0/0 All traffic
All All 0.0.0.0/0 Custom TCP Rule
TCP 0 0.0.0.0/0
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "aws_db_enpoint..." (IP...) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've also tried running other commands but have ran into the same issue.

The one command that does seem to work is the following:

```
pg_restore -v -h 'aws_db_enpoint' --port 5432 -U user_name dump.sql
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect successfully by SSH'ing into my EB server and running the command from there.